# Die with threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make a Die gui which changes the face of the die every time a different number is shown. I have a RollDie class which extends the gui class Die:

```
public class RollDie2 extends Die implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long sleeptime = 500;
    int times;
    Random rd = new Random();
    int face;
    int facebefore;

    times = rd.nextInt(20)+1;
    face = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;

    // Graphics
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            Die die = new RollDie2();

            die.setVisible(true);
          }
        });



    for (int i=0; i<times; i++) {
        (new Thread(new RollDie2(face))).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        sleeptime += 100;

        facebefore = face;
        face = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;

        while (facebefore == face) //so it is different every time
            face = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("The die was rolled " + times + " times.");



}

int face;

public RollDie2(int face) {
    this.face = face;
    super.changeFace(face);

}
public RollDie2() {

}
@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("The face is now showing: " + face);
}

}
```

And the GUI class:

```
public class Die extends JFrame {
int face;

public Die() {
    init();

}


private void init() {
    //final 
    DiePanel surface = new DiePanel();
    add(surface);
   // surface.updateVal(face);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            Timer timer = surface.getTimer();
            timer.stop();
        }
    });

    setTitle("Dice");
    setSize(500, 300);
    //setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void changeFace(int value) {
    face = value;

}
public int getFace() {
    return face;
}
}
```

The problem is every time I call **getFace()** in the panel class it returns nothing and I can't update the value of the Die. I think this has something to do with the threads but don't know what.

Comment: Your run method is just spitting out a string and nothing else.

Comment: I have invokeLater() upwards. It creates the gui.

Comment: Yes but all that does is to create a Die object and set the visibility. When does it actually roll the dice ie call your random number generator?

Comment: The value face is what is supposed to be shown.

Comment: There's no code that would show any values on the GUI.

Comment: Yes. The code is in the panel but the class seemed too long so I didnt attach it. As I said I try to update the value there with getFace() but it is just an empty int.

Answer (score 0):

I see your missing a set method. 
Also your code is all over the place. Thread's are tricky. This code below help me to run multiple thread at once. It may help your thread problem.

```
public class RollDie implements Runnable
{
//variables go here

public RollDie()
{
  start();
}

public void start()
{
 Thread thread = new thread(this);
 thread.start();
}

public void run()
{
//code for RollDie goes here
}

}
```

Then just call your RollDie constructer from your die class.
Hope this helps out.

Comment: You should not extend Thread with your class (and there is no need to either because you use it through the Runnable interface anyway). In your example code its *useless* any *extremely confusing* because you actually override the Thread.start() method to totally different semantics.

Comment: Ok I gotcha, It was from a tutorial I found online anyway's!

Comment: You are actually *creating* and *starting* _two_ threads there - the one you created by *extending* Thread (and calling super.start() in your constructor) and the other in the override of start() where you explicitly "new Thread()" and then start() that. Only the second does useful work. That may be an artifact left over of "trying many different things", but its certainly not good clean code (as if you show something like this in a job interview you are guaranteed to be declined). Simply remove the "extends Thread" and the call to super.start(). It will still work the same.